# Access to BIND 9 DNS view by authenticated user?

Tags: domain-name-system, authentication, bind, dynamic-ip

I have a network consisting of several sites.  All of the sites have a static IP address, except one.  For a variety of reasons it needs to have a dynamic address.

Now, I have all the static sites set up on my DNS server into one view.  Is there any way that I could get the dynamic IP site into the same view?  Say, have it authenticate into the view with a userid and password, or perhaps a public key?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Even if it is a dynamic IP you surely control the block, hence you could all the block as an ACL to your bind configuration to be allowed to access the view, along all static clients.

There is no concept of authentication in the DNS world.

Comment: I do not control the block.

Comment: What does that mean? You are free to put it as an ACL in your bind config